# What does the grey check mark mean on GPUOpen's Vulkan database?

Tags: gpu, vulkan

At this [website](https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=18196#formats) it shows the format capabilities of each physical device. There are green crosses, red crosses and grey crosses. I'm guessing green means that format is supported, red means not, what does grey mean? No data?

Answer (score 2):

A greyed out format line on my database means that the device does not support any format feature flag for that format and the image tiling or buffer use.

Since there is no way of directly getting a list with supported formats from a device in Vulkan I simply iterate over all formats that are defined in the headers.

P.S. : My databases are in no way affiliated with AMD's GPUOpen.

Comment: I guess it is worthwhile to address the fact that the linked website is in fact maintained by you in the answer